# Why is my Python Speech to text code not printing the text when I run it?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

My code is given below. It only outputs listening... and works indefinitely whereas it should be printing what I say to it. I am not sure what's going wrong.

I am using windows 10 and the pycharm IDE. I have successfully installed speechRecognition and Pyaudio before running the code. I have also tried recording myself from the voice recorder app in windows and I can record and hear myself clearly.

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()

try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('listening...')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(command)

except:
    print('speech not recognized')
    pass
```

Code taken from https://youtu.be/AWvsXxDtEkU

EDIT:

Looking for an answer that can achieve the same result as shown at 5:42 in the above youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

As the [microphone_recognize samples](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/microphone_recognition.py) states, you should attempt to recognize after the recording is done or triggered to be finished (after the context manager closed) so your code should be like so -

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()

try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('listening...')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
    command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
    print(command)

except:
    print('speech not recognized')
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am now able to see the text which I speak.

But how can we achieve this - When I run the program, it listens to me until I stop speaking / after a certain time and then prints the speech to text while the program is running and then the program ends automatically

The person in the video above ( https://youtu.be/AWvsXxDtEkU ) at timestamp 5:42 was able to do it without the indentation but that doesn't work for me. Seems like it worked for others as they mentioned in the comments section.

Comment: Currently after making the changes you suggested, when I run the program, just listening... gets printed. I say something and then when I stop the program then I can see the text that I spoke. That's pretty cool too but I wonder if we can make it like a voice assistant like siri or Alexa?

Comment: First, you need to understand Alexa or Siri has so much thing going on behind them which not simple to explain. Now that we got that out of the way, to keep the recording running until a certain you'll need to run a loop or thread that stops or break the listening after the mentioned period. The package is specifically for sending a audio file to recognition servers and get results. Working with live audio is a nice addition. Anyway, you probably should record using a different audio recording package which lets you specify time. I don't remember the one I used long ago..

Comment: PS If my answer worked and solved your problem consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you! I meant like Alexa. I am trying to figure out problems within my computer, python version or anything else other than the code as the person in the video executed the same code and was able to get the desired result I mentioned about. Sorry if my words were unclear. Please see the video at 5:42 for a better understanding of the desired result I am expecting.

Comment: I am happy to mark your answer as accepted answer if I can get the desired result as shown in the video ( https://youtu.be/AWvsXxDtEkU ) at 5:42

Comment: I have seen the code on the video. Its very similar to what I have shown. The change is I am parsing after the recording context is closed. And the example is attempting to parse while in the context. In both case the work similarly. The speech_recognition uses PyAudio as internal audio processing (recording, splitting etc) library. [Mentioned here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst) for your particular use case check their repo out. You can leave the question open if some can answer you to be point. Cheers and good luck.